# Bind() Windows Socket works with IPv4 but not with IPv6

Tags: c++, winsock2

I am learning how to use Winsock. I am programming a server that listens for a connection. Everything worked fine until I wanted to change the whole code over to IPv6.

I've gone through every question and website related to this topic, but no solution suited me... :/

Background: Windows, using Visual Studio 2019, IPv6 is activated and working all fine otherwise (I can ping my phone in IPv6 for example).

Every time I get error 10049. This one tells me that the given IP is invalid. I tried every one I could find in `ipconfig` and `::1`.

```
int slisten;
long res;
SOCKET client;

WSADATA wsaData;

res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
if (res == 0)
    cout << "WSAStartup()\t\t successful" << endl;
else
    cout << "error WSAStartup(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

slisten = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (slisten != INVALID_SOCKET)
    cout << "socket()  \t\t successful" << endl;
else
    cout << "error socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

//IPv6
struct sockaddr_in6 ip6addr;
ip6addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
ip6addr.sin6_port = htons(55339);
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &ip6addr.sin6_addr);

res = bind(slisten, (struct sockaddr*) & ip6addr, sizeof ip6addr);
if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    wprintf(L"bind function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}

/* IPv4, not in use
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;
ip4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip4addr.sin_port = htons(3490);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &ip4addr.sin_addr);

res = bind(slisten, (struct sockaddr*) & ip4addr, sizeof ip4addr);
if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    wprintf(L"bind function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
*/
```

The IPv4 method works, but the IPv6 doesn't.

WSAStartup() = Success

socket() = Success

bind() = Error 10049

If I comment out the IPv6 part and uncomment the IPv4 part, and change `PF_INET6` to `PF_INET` in `slisten = socket()`, there is no `bind()` error.

Tell me if you need more code or something, but I mean, if the program throws in an error at that specific function, everything until then must work fine because there are no errors (?).

Some parts of the code belong to s41b0tproductions on YouTube. You can find him at https://www.youtube.com/user/s41b0tproductions/videos.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully, it tells you how to check for errors and how to retrieve further error info. This error code can also be mapped to a string, both with a utility or programmatically. With that in mind, extract a [mcve] from your code for posting here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `socket()`, `PF_INET`/`PF_INET6` should be `AF_INET`/`AF_INET6` instead.  But this generally doesn't matter as the `PF_...` and `AF_...` macros usually map to the same numeric values.

But, more importantly, you are not zeroing out the `sockaddr_in`/`sockadr_in6` structs before filling them in.  You should always zero out Win32 API structs before using them.  For `AF_INET`, you are not populating the `sockaddr_in::sin_zero` field with zeros, so it will contain random bytes from the call stack.  Which is usually OK since that field is generally ignored.  But for `AF_INET6`, you are not populating the `sockaddr_in6::sin6_flowinfo` and `sockaddr_in6::sin6_scope_id` fields, which do have meaning, and is likely the root cause of your `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL` error when they contain random values.

Use this instead:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 ip6addr = {};
```

```
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr = {};
```

Or:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 ip6addr;
ZeroMemory(&ip6addr, sizeof ip6addr);
```

```
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;
ZeroMemory(&ip4addr, sizeof ip4addr);
```

However, a better way to create properly filled `sockaddr_in`/`sockaddr_in6` structs for `bind()` (and `connect()`) is to use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) instead of filling them manually:

```
const char szHost = "::1"; // or "127.0.0.1"
const char *szPort = "55339";

addrinfo hint = {};
hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICHOST;
hint.ai_family = AF_INET6; // or AF_INET
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *addr = NULL;
res = getaddrinfo(szHost, szPort, &hint, &addr);
if (res != 0)
{
    wprintf(L"getaddrinfo function failed with error: %d\n", res);
}
else
{
    res = bind(slisten, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"bind function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! There is a small issue, it should be `*szHost` My question is solved! Will mark it as such.